# Unreachable code? user image upload

Tags: java, android

Eclipse keeps showing me the syntax error to insert '}' to complete Classbody at the dne of my code, but when i do so, it shows a different error that the last part of the code is unreachable? What am i doing wrong?

My code:

```
  public class GetImage extends Activity {



private static final int MyImage =1;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInsatnceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInsatnceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diary_edit);

    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

}

public void btnClick(View v){
    Intent int3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(int3,MyImage);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int  requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode , resultCode , data);

    switch (requestCode){
    case MyImage :
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri=data.getData();
            String[]projection ={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};



        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver ().query(uri,projection , null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);

        String filePath=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Bitmap yourSelectedImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);

        iv.setBackground(d);
        }

        break;

        ault:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your if statement looks to be missing a close bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an } at the end of the class and ault should be default :)

Comment: When i put the '}' at the end of the class i get the 'unreachable code error.

Comment: ault: break; should be default: break; ... missing some characters.